# Excel If statement help

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I've been trying to come-up with excel formula that provide me with a answer if  the condition that i set are being met?

Example

```
Item     Records     Actual count  Diff. %    % Tolerance    Tolerance ok?
PCMA      525          541           3.0%         10.0%          Yes
PCLY      262          250           -4.6%         4.0%          No
```

But using

```
=if(and(Diff.%,%tolerance),"yes","no")
```

give me an answer of both yes..if possible to ask if there is a way that i can come up with the correction formulation.

Comment: in the case of DIFF.% is greater than Tolerance and DIFF.% is equal on the % Tolerance can you please provide me an excel formula that will provide all the answer that i seek...Thank you very much

Comment: We can’t help you if you don’t tell us what you want.  What condition(s) do you want to test?  What results do you want to get?  What do you mean by `and(Diff.%,%tolerance)`?

Comment: The AND just checks whether everything in its list is "true".  Any non-zero numeric value is interpreted as true.  You need to test for the condition you're looking for, such as Sir Adelaide suggests.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are trying to compare Diff and Tolerance, to check whether Diff is less than the allowed Tolerance:

```
=if(abs(diff)<Tolerance,"Yes","No")
```

Your *and* statement didn't do any comparisons to work out what was ok and what wasn't, so everything ended up ok.

Comment: yes it was in the given data that i gathered while working on my worksheet...but still i will try these formula that you sir/madam have provided.